# PHP Display 2 Last Row data to Last Row HTML table based on Date Added

Tags: php

```
<table>
<td>ID</td>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Date Added</td>
<tr>

<?php
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tab ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 2");

while($d = mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
echo "<td>$d['id'];</td>";
echo "<td>$d['name'];</td>";
echo "<td>$d['date_added'];</td>";
echo "<tr>";
}
```

Example, I have 4 data.
I want to get 2 last row based on date_added DESC and display it in last row HTML table td.

Please help.

Comment: do you get any errors ? what is exact problem of this code ? note that mysql is depreciated , you must use mysqli.

Comment: your while statment is not closed!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Date Added</td>
</tr>

<?php
$q = mysql_query("SELECT id,name,date_added FROM table ORDER BY  date_added DESC LIMIT 2");

while($d = mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
echo "<tr><td>".$d['id']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$d['name']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$d['date_added']."</td>";
echo "<tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```